# Is there a way to programmatically scan a webpage for the presence of a chatbot if the code loading it is hidden in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, google-tag-manager

Could I maybe scrape pages to detect loaded Javascript that's specific to various chatbot apps?

Answer (score 1):

GTM (unless you are talking about the new, server-side container type) does not hide anything (it couldn't if it wanted to, this is just javascript after all).

If the chat is implemented as custom html tag, the code will be dynamically inserted into the DOM. You can scrape for the code as long as your scraping tool executes Javascript and shows dynamically created elements.

If the Chat is implemented via a template (provided by Google, or a custom template), the code might be optimized in a way that makes it not easily recognizable. However it will still issue the same network requests. So instead of scanning for the code, you can capture the network requests e.g. with Selenium and Chromedriver - enable performance logging in desired capabilities, after you request the page retrieve the log via `chromedriver.get_log('performance'),` and then loop through the network requests until you find something that matches the chat requests.